# Building a JavaFX application

Tags: java, maven, gradle, javafx, openjfx

In Java 8 times I created a JavaFX application which I now wanted to port and build with Java 11.

First thing I did was creating a `module-info.java` and adding the required libraries.

Than I added OpenJFX dependencies to `gradle.build`:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'org.openjfx:javafx:11.0.1'
  compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-base:11.0.1'
  compile 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11.0.1'
}
```

After refreshing Gradle, I still got errors like `Cannot resolve Symbol 'javafx.beans.property.StringProperty'`.

Next thing I tried to modify the `module-info.java` like that:

```
module foo {
  requires org.apache.commons.lang3;  // another external dependency
  requires javafx.base;
  requires javafx.controls;
}
```

But this did not change anything, it I rather get the error `Module not found: javafx.base`.

Could anyone point out what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check the [getting started guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle). Gradle needs classifiers.